# Doing the maths of numbers in a listbox based on the first character of each item

Tags: c#, math, textbox, listbox

I have a program that adds items to a list box. The items consist of a character (+,-,*,/) followed by numbers. I want to get my program to recognize the first character of the item in the list box, and do the math appropriately. However, I cannot seem to get it right. I'm not even sure what code I should be using.

Just to make it a little more clear

Items get entered into a textbox called `txtCalculation` using this format "+34233". That value is then added into the list box `lstDisplay` so after 5 items it should look like this.

```
+2
+4
/2
-1
+5
*3
total = 21
```

I would like to find a way to make the program go through the list and do the math, and then add it as a final item to the list as shown above. I already have the code to add the numbers to the list and an attempt to add them together and then put them in a textbox called `txtTest`, but everytime I add a new number txtTest is just set to the last number I added to the listbox instead of displaying the overall total of these numbers

Code that I have so far

```
        double total = 0;
        string line = "";
        if (txtCalculation.Text.Length > 1)
        {

            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            {
                string Number = txtCalculation.Text;
                try
                {
                    switch (Number[0])
                    {
                        case '+':
                            total += Convert.ToInt32(Number.Substring(1));
                            break;
                        case '-':
                            total -= Convert.ToInt32(Number.Substring(1));
                            break;
                    }
                    lstDisplay.Items.Add(Number);
                    txtCalculation.Text = "";
                    txtTest.Text = total.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error");
                }
            }
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me fix this code up and explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Simply listing your requirements and asking for help is not a good way to ask a question on this site. Please see [Why is "Can someone Help me" not an "actual" question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work.

Comment: The first part is explaining what I want it to do
the rest is what ive tried to do to solve the problem

sooooo....
show us how you tried to solve the problem (check) code shown above.
show exactly what the result was (check) txtTest is being set to 0 instead of the total of the numbers.

maybe you can suggest a different website because im new to coding and would very much appreciate people who are willing to help me understand how things work

Comment: I think you need to make total a class variable. Every time this event fires you declare a local total variable and set it to zero, so you're only adding,subtracting,multiplying, or dividing the last entered number one time against total (which is starting at zero) every time this event fires.  It sounds like you want each value to calculate into a running total, so making it a class variable should fix this.  However, as a class variable you're going to want a way to reset total back to zero at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a small example on this:

```
<Window x:Class="AddTotalListConverter.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AddTotalListConverter"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:ComputationConverter x:Key="ComputationConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView x:Name="lvNumbers" ItemsSource="{Binding numbers}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Numbers">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10">
            <TextBlock Text="New Number" Margin="5,0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="tbNewNumber" MinWidth="50" Margin="5,0"/>
            <Button Content="Add Number" Margin="5,0" Click="btnAddNumber_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding numbers.Count, Converter={StaticResource ComputationConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Reference lvNumbers}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This is the View. Nothing too fancy, just the ListView bounded to the ObservableCollection numbers. The TextBlock which will display the total is bounded to the items count. So, every time you add or remove an item, it will be updated. A converter is present there and its parameter is the ListView itself.

```
class ComputationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int result = 0;
        ListView lv = parameter as ListView;
        Console.WriteLine(lv.Items);
        foreach (var item in lv.Items)
        {
            result += (int)item;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Again, i kept it simple without string parsings just to finish it on time, coffee time, sorry.

Indeed i work with ints, you will receive string, parse the sign and take the value also in order to continue with your case switches flow.

Here is the code behing:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> numbers { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        numbers = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void btnAddNumber_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbNewNumber.Text))
        {
            numbers.Add(int.Parse(tbNewNumber.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

If you need an MVVM approach i could make an update later, using commands and having the list in the ViewModel. 
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to assume, but the code you provided above appears to be code inside of a method which is not provided as part of your code snip. There are two options to fix your problem, if my assumptions are correct. The first option would be to move your "total" variable out of the method and give it a class scope. By declaring the variable "total" inside your method, you are clearing it to 0 every time your method is called. Giving it a class scope should keep the value of the variable every time you call the method/event. The second option would be set the value of your "total" variable to txtTest.Text. You would have to convert txtTest.Text to a double. There are a few different ways to convert a string to a double. You can research the following methods: double.Parse(string input), double.TryParse(string input, out double output), or Convert.ToDouble(string input) to do the conversion.